# Having trouble with associative array structure in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Not quite sure how to phrase this question but I'm having trouble with the structure of an associate array in a class I'm writing. The relevant parts of the code goes something like this:

```
class User {

    public $userData;

    function getUserData() {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id = :id');
        $stmt->execute(array('id' => $this->ID));
        $row = $stmt->fetchAll();

        foreach($row AS $key => $val) {
            $this->userData[$key] = $val;
        }
        return $this->userData;
    }
```

I want to be able use this to set class properties so I can access them like so:

```
$this->userData['username'];
```

for example, but this isn't working for me. Instead I have to access them like this for it to work:

```
$this->userData[0]['username'];
```

I'm having to add the array index on to access any of the data, which I don't want to be doing but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Related manual entries: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php and http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with how [PDOStatement::fetchAll()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns row data.

Even though you're only selecting a single row, it will still be returned with a row index (of zero), i.e., if you did this

```
print_r($row);
```

You'd get something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => Roy
            [0] => Roy
        )
)
```

*Note that by default, fetchAll() returns each column twice in the data - once by column name and once by column index*

The fact that you named your variable `$row` is probably part of what's tripping you up - semantically that should be `$rows`.

To fix this, you have a couple few choices

1. Directly access the first row in the result

   ```
   $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Notice the addtion of the
   foreach($rows[0] AS $key => $val)
   ```
2. Use [PDOStatement::fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) instead

   ```
   $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Notice the addtion of the
   foreach($row AS $key => $val)
   ```

But in both cases, the for loop is unnecessary. You could simply do

```
$this->userData = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Lastly, I must question why `User::$userData` is public but you've also written a getter for it (which, academically speaking, isn't even a getter - it's a fetcher)

### A few notes on getters

It's not uncommon for people to use **get** as the verb of choice when writing methods that return something. However, there is an equally broad school of thought that getters should be restricted to returning class members *only*. Where I work, we have these lines in our coding standard regarding the naming of methods

- Methods which are not property getters or setters SHOULD avoid using `get` and `set` as a prefix

  - Possible **get** alternatives: find, fetch, acquire, locate, pull, access
  - Possible **set** alternatives: push, apply, make, post, mark, attach, assign

This means developers are allowed to write `get*()` methods that *don't* just return a class property, but they're encouraged not to.

So when I say "fetcher", that is a colloquial term, and not really part of the common software engineering vernacular.

### A better approach

Here's an example where we've applied some [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) rigor. The "getting" and "fetching" of the user data each have their own implementation i.e., their own method.

```
class User
{
  private $userData = null;

  /**
   * Lazy-load-style getter for $userData
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function getUserData()
  {
    if (null === $this->userData)
    {
      $this->userData = $this->fetchUserData();
    }
    return $this->userData;
  }
  
  /**
   * Fetch the user's data from the database
   *
   * @return array Associative array of user data where the keys
   *               are column names
   */
  private function fetchUserData()
  {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->execute(array('id' => $this->ID));

    return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
}
```

Although I'd suggest adding a guard check to `User::fetchUserData()` in case `PDO::fetch()` returns **FALSE**. Perhaps something like

```
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (false === $user)
{
  throw new Exception("User with id ($this->ID) not found");
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for including both a fix and explanation. I'm self-taught so I haven't had any formal education on this, I pick these things up as I go along. As such the difference between a getter and fetcher is a bit lost on me as I've never heard of a fetcher before. Google isn't returning much; is a fetcher simply something which fetches from a data source while a getter gets a class property?

Comment: It depends on how strict of a coding environment one works in that determines what `get*()` methods are allowed to do. I'll update my answer with some more info.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `$stmt->fetchAll()`, in your query it does imply that you are trying to get a single row. You need to replace it with `$stmt->fetch()`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because in your example the $key to each row is the row index, so your assignment statement is, for row 0:

```
$this->userData[0] = $val;
```

What you want to do instead is to assign the values to the array using the value of two fields (I'm guessing):

```
$this->userData[$val['field1']] = $val['field2'];
```

Or,

```
$this->userData['username'] = $val['username'];
```

However, the real problem is that, I think, you're trying to get a single row and pulling an array of results instead -- and the inadvertently iterating over rows, instead of what you think are fields.

If you're looking for a single user record, then you need to use associative single fetch, instead of fetchAll:

```
class User {

public $userData;

function getUserData() {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->execute(array('id' => $this->ID));
    $this->userData = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $this->userData;
}
```